# Does a function expression remember the closure as a snapshot, or as a some kind of reference?

Tags: javascript, events, closures, counter, addeventlistener

I tried to make my own implementation of a click counter. It works, but I dont understand how the `store` variable, which literally stores the closure for `abc()`, at a time when `count=0`, is able to edit the value of `count` in the closure, every time that it is called. Isn't it supposed to be an immutable snapshot?

```
function xyz(){
    let count=0;
    function abc(){
        return ++count;    
    }
    
    return abc;
}

var store = xyz();

document.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log(store());
});
```

Comment: As proven by your own example, closures don't take snapshots, they update the outside variables via reference. `count` never re initializes because you don't call xyz again

Comment: @Undo `count` would not be re-initialized even if you called `xyz` again, that would create a new closure.